# develop own mobile app connecting with external gps receiver

Tags: gps, android, mobile, trimble

I want to develop a mobile app that can use external GPS as source for collecting high accurate point.

And I just found how to connect Trimble R1 or Trimble R2 to android device using bluetooth based on 'GNSS status' App and allowing 'Mock Location' on developer options in the android device...

So, I just wonder how to apply the same issue with other Trimble devices such as R3 and R4?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to detail your efforts to solve the problem.  Even though you are not a *new* user, you haven't yet taken the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) which might help you focus this into an answerable question

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you are comparing apples to apples here. The R1 and R2 are are MGIS products (I realize the R2 can also be used by Trimble Access) and the use of 3rd party software is more likely, whereas the R3 (L1 only), R4 all the way to the R10 are survey receivers. The survey receivers typically require a specialized software, like Trimble Access to configure and utilize. Once configured you could send the NMEA data to a 3rd party device if that device supports the bluetooth connection or a cabled connection.

Trimble may have some sort of SDK for their survey GNSS receivers, but it is doubtful.

I would recommend contacting a local Trimble dealer or Trimble themself. We did the same with Leica when we wanted more information on the Android version of their Zeno 20 device. It was easy to navigate their channels and even easier to work with on the questions we had.